# Effects of relativity on New Horizons spacecraft

Tags: homework-and-exercises, relativity, time-dilation, estimation, space-mission

How much would an atomic clock on board the new horizons spacecraft drift in comparison to an atomic clock on the surface of the earth near the equator after the spacecraft's 10 year journey to Pluto?

Comment: The people in charge of monitoring the systems on these spacecraft adjust the onboard clocks to keep them "aligned" with those on Earth.  They can never be truly synchronized, but they try to keep them within some set uncertainty that is defined, usually, by the mission requirements.

Comment: Info on New Horizons: https://pluto.jhuapl.edu/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say its moving roughly 32,500 mph or about 16.316 km/s relative to the Earth. If we consider special relativity then we have ten years of seconds divided by the square root of one minus 16 kilometers per second squared over the speed of light squared. The answer turns out to be roughly half a second!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To put some numbers in @Alex reply, I used the estimated travel distance of 5 billion km and 9.5 years travel time to compute the speed dilation to be 0.346 seconds.

Those numbers were gleaned from internet articles.

Comment: Something's wrong with those numbers. New Horizons was launched in 2006. It's currently ~8.7 billion km from Earth, with a mean velocity ~13.6 km/s relative to Earth. Note that's lower than Earth's orbital velocity, so for part of the year New Horizons' velocity relative to Earth is negative. That also applies to the Voyagers, see my answer https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55927/16685

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail.  The fact that the radial velocity is sometimes negative doesn't decrease dilation.  The dilation depends on the square of the relative speed between earth clocks and New Horizons.    The graph for New Horizons should show the square of the speed for evaluating dilation.  The average dilation would depend on the mean of the Lorentz gamma factor (which depends on v^2). I agree a more exact calculation of that integral would be better than the rough back  of the envelope estimate.